# Mux gets damaged the moment power is on. How do I know that cause of this?

Tags: power, multiplexer, 12v

I am currently using a mux, ADG1419, and i have had frequent mux failure the moment I turn on power; the power and the GND of the mux shorts after the mux gets damaged. My only assumption is that the failure of mux is due to voltage transient; therefore, I will add a tvs diode. I cannot think of anything beside the voltage transient. Can you think of one?

Comment: Schematic would be important but are you sure you dont have a short somewhere? Bad pcb connections?

Comment: Schematic, schematic, schematic

Comment: I have measured the pin to pin connection multiple times using DMM, and I couldn't find any shorts.

Comment: Can't be answered without a schematic. Voting to close :( Don't worry, close votes can be reverted – please add your schematic!

Comment: Probably you are exceeding one or more of the Abs. Max ratings. Schematic would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some analog multiplexers are prone to latch-up and self-destruction if the voltages at the analog inputs exceed the supply voltage and sufficient current is available from the analog input to cause damage.

This can happen if for example the multiplexer was being used to select power supply voltages, or any other signal with high drive capability, into an A/D converter for measurement.

If, at power-on, the signal being measured was to rise above the supply rails for the multiplexer, current can flow through the protection diodes internal to the multiplexer. If enough current flows it can trigger parasitic SCR devices to cause high currents to flow with the possibility for self-destruction.

One way to minimize the chances of this occurring is to provide enough resistance in series with the analog sources to limit the current under these conditions.

Alternatively there are a few devices that are designed to avoid the problem.

The linked article suggests a couple of other solutions, such as diodes in the supply rail.

[Winning the battle Against Latchup](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/winning-the-battle-against-latchup.html)

Comment: Thank you, Kevin. I added about 100ohms which was enough to protect the multiplexer.